# one-to-one relationship in database

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, data-modeling

Suppose that I have a table `users`, with a PK `id_user`.

I also have an identifying relationship between the table `users` and the table `employer`. I can use the PK `id_user` as foreign key in the table `employer` and also as PK (with unique constrain) in this table?

In this case, the employer only have a worker and a worker only have an employer.

Comment: I'm not sure I got it, is this -"the employer only have a worker and a worker only have an employer." a requirement or an unwanted product of your solution?

Comment: in this case is a requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: Yes.  When a foreign key is also the primary key of the child table it forces it into a one-to-one.

Longer answer: in my experience every 1-to-1 I've every made has been expanded later into a 1-to-many or many-to-many, as the users' requirements are better understood.  Example:  You end up needing a history of employers, so suddenly you have a many-to-many from persons to employers with effective dates.

After this happened a few times I made it a point to dig into the reasons why a 1-to-1 seemed to make sense, and always found it did not.  So much so that I made a rule of thumb for myself to avoid 1-to-1 tables, as they usually indicate an incomplete understanding of requirements.

Comment: +1.  It seems strange to have a 1:1 relationship between Users and Employers.  Can there _really_ only be one User for each Employer?

Answer (score 0):

Primary keys are special unique keys. In this case I would not link worker in the employers table as typically an employer has more then one worker. If you're absolutely sure it is a one-one relation, I do not see why you use 2 tables, instead of one. Meaning, add the employer fields to the worker table. A real one-one relation is for example a phone number or email address and typically they are stored with the owner, not in a seperate table.